# Where to ask questions about choosing of tools

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, software-recs-se

Stack Overflow denies questions like "Please advice me a library for" as opinion-based. Where on Stack Exchange can one ask this kind of questions?

Answer (score 6):

Following [their rules](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), such questions **may** be on topic at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

**Nowhere else.**